# Retrieving elements from a Dynamic array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, dynamic

*Preface*

I'm trying to implement a **Dictionary** data structure that stores Pairs(an object) in a dynamic array.

The array starts off with size [10]. Every time the user tries to add another Pair to the **Dictionary** when the array is full; the dynamic array increments the length of the array by 5.

There are 3 relevant methods.

**put:** Adds a pair to the dynamic array

**dynamicArray:** Increases the size of the array when full

**get:** Retrieves a specific element from the array

*Problem*

When the **dynamicArray** is called to be initialized with many elements, the elements don't seem to be properly stored. When trying to **get** the elements, it catches a NoSuchElementException which indicates the values were not stored in the first place.
Here is the relevant code, thank you.

```
public Token get (String key) throws NoSuchElementException,
                                         NullPointerException{
        boolean found=false; //Represents if pair is found
        Token token = null;
        if (key ==null)
            throw new NullPointerException ();

        for (int i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if ( array[i]!=null && array[i].getKey() == key){
                found=true;
              return (array[i]).getToken(); 


            }   
        }
        if (found!=true)
            throw new NoSuchElementException ();
            return  token;

        }

private void dynamicArray(){
        if (array[array.length-1]!=null){
            Pair[]replace = new Pair[array.length+5];
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, replace, 0, array.length);
            array=replace;
        }
    }

public void put  (String key, Token value) throws NullPointerException{


        if (key == null || value == null)
            throw new NullPointerException ();

        dynamicArray();
        Pair p1 = new Pair (key,value);

        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if (array[i]== null ){
                dynamicArray();
                array[i]=p1;

                break;

            }   
            }   
    }
```

**TestCase**

```
@Test()
    public void testPutDyncamicArray() {
        System.out.println("test: testPutDyncamicArray");
        Dictionary dict = new Dictionary();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            dict.put("X" + i, new Token(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            Assert.assertEquals(new Token(i), dict.get("X" + i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably use a `Map` here. What is `array`?

Comment: We're limited to using Dynamic arrays. array represents an array of Pairs. A pair consists of a (String,Token)

Comment: Also note that using `==` with `String` is wrong and that is probably the issue here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your keys are `String`, you need to use the `equals` method for checking key equality:

```
if (array[i] != null && array[i].getKey().equals(key)){
    return array[i].getToken(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that a HashMap (or just a Map) will do what you want with a lot less effort.

Comment: This question sounds like a [tag:homework] question.